# $.each() index start number in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I start jQuery `$.each()` index from 1 instead of 0?

I am using .each function to populate select box. So here I want to populate options in the select box from 1. So based on a condition I want to add option in first index i.e 0.

Comment: You can't escape zero based indexes if you want to do any serious programming.

Comment: @ChaosPandion this depends. If you are using for example the first row in a table as an example row while the others have inputs, you want to start at `i=1` to read from the inputs (or maybe you are right `:not(:first-child)`). :)

Comment: @Radek - I'm simply playing the odds that they meant for the index to always start at `1` no matter the situation.

Comment: Bearing in mind this was asked 6 years ago, is it an [array](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback) or an [object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/#jQuery-each-object-callback) being passed to [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)?

Answer (score 9):

[`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

So try

```
$.each(obj, function(i, elem) {
    if (i === 0) return;
    // do stuff
});
```

Alternatively rewrite your code so its so indexes and data start at 0. JavaScript is interally 0 based rather then 1 based like Matlab and some other languages.

Comment: This would skip the last element. So he would have to manually access the last element as the each loop would fall short by one

Comment: @Victor, this would skip the first element, not the last.

Comment: @Victor what makes you think that? WRONG.

Comment: If he has 10 elements (starting at 1), and access them in this loop using i, then he would never access the last element, since the loop would en at 9.

Comment: Im no expert, so if Im wrong I would be more than happy to retract.

Comment: @Victor we mis intepreted the question. I assume has has 10 elements indexed 0 to 9 and he wants to ignore element 0 and only deal with elements 1 - 9

Comment: @Victor If the array has 10 elements (indexes `0` through `9`), this code will skip the element at index `0` (the first element), and then process the elements from index `1` to `9` (the remaining elements).

Comment: @Victor: How's that retraction coming along? ;o)

Comment: @patric et all. I dont think a retraction is in order, but again i could be wrong. Here I added my comments to what my view is on this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/u75Pg/1/ I do respect your opinions, and I either didnt explain myself correctly or im just losing it.

Comment: @Raynos @jball I believe the OP wanted to go 1-10; and this loop effectively misses #10 which is I think that using `var myIndex = index + 1` is a better solution and hope that clarifies my point. cheers!

Comment: @Victor: Alright, you're saying that there will never be an actual "number 10", and that's what OP wants. The trouble is that your comment stated *"this would skip the last element"*. You didn't define what you meant by *"element"*. An element to me sounds more like an item referenced by the Array. Apparently you're defining element as the modified index. Makes more sense now.

Comment: Agreed and it was pointed that I had the benefit of reading one of his comments. I still thought the reaction was a bit overboard but no big deal. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

You can't. Why not just declare another variable at the first line of the function `var myIndex = index + 1;`?

Comment: Yes, I think that's what the question is referring to.

Answer (score 4):

You can start at any given starting value by simply adding that number to the current loop-set index value.

```
$.each(arrayOrObject, ( index ) => {

    index += 1 //or any other starting value
    if (items[index] === undefined)
        return false;

    // your code
});
```

#### EDIT

One comment said it doesn't work, so [here](https://jsfiddle.net/S3C_MM/zcxwL0gr/6/)'s a working code. You see the results in console.

```js
$('#go').click((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const items = $('.item');
  const startingNumber = $('#startingNumber').val() * 1;

  $.each(items, (index) => {

    index += startingNumber;

    if (items[index] === undefined)
      return false; //this prevents the loop to go on after reaching the end

    console.log(items[index]);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: .2em;
    margin-top: 1em;
  }
  
  .item {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 30px;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: .5em;
  }
</style>

<input id="startingNumber" type="number" min="0" max="5" value="1">
<input id="go" type="submit">

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item">0</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You should elaborate on your answer

Comment: @FilT It always worked. Just added a working example.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. `jQuery.each` loops over Objects (Arrays). For real objects, it uses a `for in` loop. Objectpropertys don't have a guaranteed index at all by the way.

For Arrays it uses standard `for loop`, but you don't have access to the starting index.

Your best shot is to just skip the first element.

```
$.each(obj, function(index, elem) {
    if( index === 0 )
        return true;

    // code
});
```

Comment: Either write it on one line or use brackets!

Comment: This would skip the last element. So he would have to manually access the last element as the each loop would fall short by one

Comment: @Victor, why would it skip the last element?

Comment: @Victor: That is BS - and downvoting..really outclassed yourself.

Comment: @jAndy Wow. 1. How is it BS? If he has 10 elements (starting at 1), and access them in this loop using i, then he would never access the last element, since the loop would end at 9. 2) How did i outclass myself? First, is not personal, the whole point of voting is to vote up the correct answer, and vote down incorrect ones. I seldomly vote down but i felt this answer was incorrect given what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Victor: just look at http://www.jsfiddle.net/u75Pg/ I either don't understand what you mean or you are terribly wrong.

Comment: @jAndy I believe the OP wanted to go 1-10; and this loop effectively misses #10 which is why I think that using `var myIndex = index + 1` is a better solution and hope that clarifies my point. cheers!

Comment: @Victor: well, I guess we just look at things differently. never mind.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the clarification points in the comments below, `jQuery.each` or some variation thereof isn't the right tool at all. Use a for loop, and add 1 to the index to output the value of the `<option>`.

Use `.prepend` to insert an `option` as the first child of a `select`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('select').prepend('<option>' + (i + 1) + '</option>');
}
```

Comment: Ew. `:gt` just feels slow and wrong. I would go for complete refactoring before using that.

Comment: I am using .each function to populate select box,So here i want to populate option box from 1,So based on condition i want to add option in first index i.e 0.

Comment: @Raynos are you ok with using `:first, :eq, :last`? `:gt` is implemented in exactly the same way - it's a filter function internally.

Comment: @user, so you're tryring to add new `<option>` elements to a single `<select>`? Is the select initially empty? And do you want your options to contain the numbers starting from 1?

Comment: Box9:yes your right,If i want to add any new option,i will add it to 0 index.I dont really need jquery solution .I am ok with Simple Javascript solution.

Comment: @user See my updated answer - **but** you really need to edit your question to make it clearer. Tell us **exactly** what you're trying to do. `jQuery.each` isn't even the right method to use here, so you're getting a bunch of irrelevant answers.

Comment: @box9 This was my understanding of what the OP was trying to do, hence my comments on the other answers

Comment: @Victor, then you have miraculous understanding! I only changed my answer after the OP's comments on it. On a side note, the reactions to your comment were... over-reactive.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [42, 1337];
$.each(data, function(i) {
  i++;
  console.log(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
var start = index + 1;
```

This just adds 1 to the current index.. then use that new variable instead of 'index'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following if

```
$.each(function (elem, index) {
  if(elem > 0 ) {
    //do it
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.article_number').each(function(index) {
    index=index+1;
    $(this).text(index);
});
```

even starting from 0 each time it takes the index and adds one for the text.

so 0 will become 1 in text.
1 will become 2 in text and so on.

This won't interrupt the last item in line cause it's only changing the index of the text not on the each function.

Hope this is what you ment.