# Javascript and Select box

Tags: javascript

I have select box with options starts from 0 index.So here I want to add option tag at zero index without deleting or replacing the original zero index option element.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Do you mean just add the option to the beginning of the list?

Comment: Please edit your previous question with this new information. Don't ask a new one. Though I commend you on being much clearer now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery .each index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892282/jquery-each-index)

Answer (score 1):

```
var select = document.getElementById('myselect');
var newoption = document.createElement('option');
newoption.value = 0; // or whatever
newoption.innerHTML = '0'; // or whatever
select.insertBefore(newoption, select.options[0]);
```

Comment: Setting newoption.value did not work for me. Maybe newoption.text or newoption.textContent is the way to go. Try it out http://jsfiddle.net/JJUXa/

Comment: If you want to see some text, you have to provide an `innerHtml`-value(text only works for FF and innerText only for IE): `newoption.innerHTML = "this is a new option";`

Comment: @JoeRobich `innerHTML` is the way to go. Had forgotten to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Any javascript library that allows you to manipulate the inner html of the `<select>` will have to copy all options to a temp array, delete them, add the one you want, and finally add the options in the temp array.

You maytry this with JQuery:

`$('.selector').prepend('<option value="value">text</option>')` but i doubt it will work.

Comment: Um, have you tried it? [Your code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/XJSLE/1/), [as does mine](http://jsfiddle.net/XJSLE/).

Comment: @lonesomeday: yes, but internally JQuery does reshuffle the array of Options in JS. Even the insertBefore() does the same thing (only difference is that it is built into the dom/browser, not with explicit javascript). Therefore it is virtually impossible, unless the array of Options inside a Select is implemented as a LinkedList... (which I hardly doubt).