# how to draw the graph without taking first four columns of the table in chart.js

Tags: javascript

I need to draw the graph without taking the values of first four columns in the table. Here is the javascript code

```
  $('#modChart').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var link = $(event.relatedTarget);
    // get data source
    var source = link.attr('data-source').split(',');
    // get title
    var title = link.html();
    // get labels
    var table = link.parents('table');
    var labels = [];
    $('#' + table.attr('id') + '>thead>tr>th').each(function(index, value) {
        // without first column
        if (index > 0) {
            labels.push($(value).html());
        }
    });
    // get target source
    var target = [];
    $.each(labels, function(index, value) {
        target.push(link.attr('data-target-source'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$.each` You can use a simple for-loop with an index starts with 4,
or set a condition inside the $.each loop, like so:

```
$.each(labels, function(index, value) {
    if( index >= 4 ){
        target.push(link.attr('data-target-source'));
    }
});
```

for reference:
[each-index-start-number-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892282/each-index-start-number-in-jquery)